# How do I configure a chart webpart?

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part, pivot-tables

I have a service desk task list that tracks the number of service requests by service person and is filtered by certain criteria. These tasks are tracked on an hourly basis. I'm new to Chart web parts and can't figure out how to configure the chart. Here is the scenario:

Tasks have 2 statuses that are tracked in the Task Status column:

- NOT STARTED

  COMPLETED

When a task is COMPLETED, it has 2 child statuses which are tracked in the Review column:

- COMPLETE

  INCOMPLETE

If a COMPLETED task is given a Review status of INCOMPLETE, it means that more data is needed from the Requestor and to expect another task to be generated in the future. The status of INCOMPLETE is tracked so they know how many they need to circle back to.

On an **hourly basis**, by individual the tasks are **Assigned To**, I need to track:

- The total number of NOT STARTED tasks

  The total number of COMPLETED tasks

  Of the COMPLETED task total, I need to know the number of INCOMPLETE
  child statuses (the number of COMPLETE and INCOMPLETE child statuses
  needs to be reflected in the COMPLETED task total)

I'm thinking the chart should look like this:

- X axis = Task Status and Review Status

  Y axis = Hourly Breakdown

  Assigned To = Color of bars

How do I get the status from 2 different columns to display on the X axis?
Having the hourly breakdown on the Y axis will result in a huge chart. Can I have people flip through my chart on a daily/weekly/monthly view?
Is a chart even the best way to view this data? Should I simply make a pivot table in Excel and use some sort of Excel Viewer web part that will let me display the pivot table?

I'm not sure what my options are, but I know there has to be a way to view tasks by status on an hourly basis by who the tasks are assigned to.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is a good option to analyse the progress of your tasks.

To view tasks by status and by who the tasks are assigned to try the following:

Create an excel pivot table by adding Assigned to (1) and Task name (2) to the Rows

Add status to the columns.
Sum by count of status and
Filter by Status

Comment: Thank you. I've been playing around with a Pivot Table and I think that may be the way to go. I'm not a Pivot Table expert and I'm having trouble displaying the data the way the team wants it. Excel puts the status as the column heading, but the team wants that data along the bottom with a subtotal. I'm not sure how to render this chart the way they want it.